# Prevent divs from wrapping to new line and display on one scrollable row

Tags: php, css, forced-unwrapping

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

#moviesbox{
 white-space: nowrap;
 background-color: #363e4f;
 width:4000px;
 position:absolute;
 overflow:auto;

}

.slider {
    position: relative;
 width: 155px;
 display: inline-block;
    background-color: #D4D4D4;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
 height: 300px; 
 padding: 3px; 
 white-space: normal;
}







h1 {
    color: #00ff00;
}

p {
    background-color: transparent;
 color: #ffffff;
}

div
{
 color: #00cc00;
}


div #controls
{
 color: red;
}

div a
{
 color: #00cc00;
}

div a:active {
 color: #00cc00;
}

div a:hover {
 color: #F58100;
}




<!--/MAIN PANEL/-->
#parent {
 width:400px;
}

#controls, #monitor {
 float:left;
 margin-top:0px;
 padding-below:200px;
 height:400px;
 width:50%; 
 border:1px; 
 display:inline-block;
 solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
 text-align:center;

}


<!--/CONTENT AND CONTROLS/-->

#detail {
    width:320px;
    height:180px;
    margin-bottom:12px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}


h1text {
    color: #fb667a;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
 float:left;
 width:159px;
 white-space:pre-wrap;
 background: transparent;

}



.year {
float:left;
background: transparent;

 
}
img {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 background:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
    transform: scale(1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #00cc00;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #00cc00;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #00cc00;
  
}
img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
 cursor:pointer;
    transform: scale(1);
    visibility:visible;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transform: scale(1.1); 
    z-index:100;
    transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.1, 1);
    transition-duration:400ms;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;  /* remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
/* optional: show position indicator in red */
/*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #FF0000;
}*/











#detail div {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#detail div img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height: 400px;
    z-index:1;
}
#detail div span {
    color:#ffffff;
    position:absolute;
 margin
    bottom:0;
 right:0;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    background: #00cc00;
    opacity: .8;
    z-index:2;
}
#detail div span2 {
    color:#ffffff;
    position:absolute;
 top:200px;
 right:10px;
    text-align:center;
    width:50%;
 height:200px;
    background: #F58100;
    opacity: .8;
    z-index:10;
}
#links img {
    width:10%;
    height:30%;
    margin-left:16px;
 margin-top:100px;
}

<!--/SLIDER/-->





.track {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;

    width: 2000px;
}
.book {
    float: left;
    
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
.book:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.book:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.book:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #ffaa00;
}
.book:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #ffff00;
}
.book:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: #00ff00;
}
.book:nth-child(5) {
    background-color: #0000ff;
}
.book:nth-child(6) {
    background-color: #aa00ff;
}
.book:nth-child(7) {
    background-color: #ff00ff;
}
.left, .right {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 48px;
    top: 57px;
    
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
}
.left {
    left: 0;
}
.right {
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<?php
//database connection
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$db = 'pixbeans';

/* 1) mysqli and mysqli result objects */

//$mysqli is object of mysqli class
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db); 
//print_r($mysqli);die;

//call query method of $mysqli object
$result = $mysqli->query 
        //SELECT queries are always return as mysqli result objects
        ("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE year BETWEEN 2000 AND 2016 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 20") 
        or die($mysqli->error); 

?>



<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>pixBeans - Original Black TV Series</title>
   <meta name="author" content="Antonio James">
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/Icons/pixBeans icon.png">
   <link href="tabpan.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>


<style>*{margin: 0px;  padding: 0px; background-color:black;}</style>

<body>
<div id="main-wrapper">




<div id="moviesbox" style="display:inline-block;"> 
 

<?php while ($movie = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>    

    <div id="left1" class="left">&lt;</div>
  <div id="right1" class="right">&gt;</div>   
     
     <div class="slider"  >
   <img width='<?php 67*2.3 ?>' height='<?= 98*2.3 ?>' src='<?= $movie['image_url'] ?>'> <br>
   <h1text><?= $movie['title'] ?></h1text> <br>
   <span class='year'>(<?= $movie['year'] ?>)</span>
     </div>               
</div> 
   
<?php endwhile; ?>    
 
 
 
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>  
<script src="javascript/tabpan.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/imgjump.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/imgslider.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to make all my images display on one horizontal line/row that can be scrolled left or right. However, no matter what I do I cannot seem to make the images quit wrapping to the next line. They are responsive so if i make the screen small 2 images will appear and the rest wraps to a new line. If i make full screen several images appear and the other 15 wrap accordingly. However, I want them to stay on one line. I dont care if the overflow is hidden or if the overflow scrolls in from off the page,  I just want them to quit wrapping.

Here is what the site looks like right now:

[screen shot. I made the parent div"moviesbox" dark grey so that you can see how far the div extends and I am using light grey to show the div area.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3kjc.jpg)

Here is the code that I am using to generate the images into the divs:

```
<div id="moviesbox" style="display:inline-block;">
```

fetch_assoc()): ?>

```
    <div id="left1" class="left">&lt;</div>
    <div id="right1" class="right">&gt;</div>   

    <div class="slider"  >
        <img width='<?php 67*2.3 ?>' height='<?= 98*2.3 ?>' src='<?= $movie['image_url'] ?>'> <br>
        <h1text><?= $movie['title'] ?></h1text> <br>
        <span class='year'>(<?= $movie['year'] ?>)</span>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS I am using. I PREFER TO USE CSS but if not, i'm open to other fixes.

```
#moviesbox{
white-space: nowrap;
background-color: #363e4f;
width:4000px;
position:absolute;
overflow:auto;
}

.slider {
position: relative;
width: 155px;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #D4D4D4;
margin-bottom: 2em;
height: 300px; 
padding: 3px; 
white-space: normal;
}
```

THanks.

Comment: If you want strict format and no wrapping, remove responsive mode then.  That will fix the width to a certain value.

Comment: Is there not a way to keep it responsive, yet fix it to not wrap?

Comment: Do research for fixed width and responsive.  I saw this: https://codepen.io/winghouchan/pen/wcrAI and others about it.

Comment: ive been doing research 2 months. Ive also had 2 of my school buddies try and we cannot figure it out and nothing we've saw online worked.

Comment: I just tried taking the fix width element out. Without it, things got really funky

Comment: CSS can be a fiddly beast. Here is a quickie jsfiddle which does what you were thinking? https://jsfiddle.net/xob6ynqs/

Comment: Oh wait, you want moviesbox to auto-adjust to the width of the window if its resized? Hmmmmmmmmm. Without some js in the mix... this could be tricky :)

Comment: Oh, So i'm going to need JS. Randall?

Comment: No need for JS.

Comment: I always use now css flex property; yours is perfect use case with `flex:nowrap` check here https://loading.io/flexbox/

Comment: the flex worked. Thanks guys.